# jQuery: Doubleckick outside of content

Tags: jquery, double-click

I have a content with with a width of 720px in the middle of a body. I want, if people press doubleclick outside of that content to do function using jQuery.

I know how I could do the `if double click on the body` but that includes the content aswell so I'd liked to know how can I exclude some div's and classes.

Thanks alot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply stop the propagation of the dblclick event from the content to the rest of the document:

```
$('#content').dblclick(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

With this, any double click event on the #content element will not be received by any of its parent.

So the following handler will not receive dbclick events for double clicks on the content element:

```
$(document).dblclick(function() {
    // ....
});
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/E4tZQ/

See [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can set another doubleclick handler to the container of your content (720px) 
which has [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) inside and **returns false;**

```
$('#myContentDiv').bind('dblclick', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  return false; 
});
```

[event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) works too.

Comment: Returning false from a handler is equivalent to calling both .preventDefault() and .stopPropagation() on the event object ;-) You need only stopPropagation().

Comment: I agree that all 3 will do the trick :) So your answer is correct too.

Answer (score 0):

You need both a way to test for the double click, and to stop propagation when the content div is clicked:

http://jsfiddle.net/STchX/